# How to find partial text in multiple elements with Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm trying to find partial text inside web page's `<p>` elements, which contains specific string. While I know how to find the whole text, I don't know how to find only a partial text, if it matches.

For example, if a text between p tags contains "Lorem ipsum" and my string is "ipsum", the script should find it in the text.

Here's my code so far:

```
#elem = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('p').text
elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//p[contains(text(), ' "+string" ')]").get_attribute('text')

if title in elem:
    print(title)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You missed one concatenation `+`

try now.

```
string="ipsum"

elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//p[contains(text(), '" + string + "')]").text
```

The other way is to do it using python **format** function.

```
string="ipsum"

elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//p[contains(text(), '{string}')]").text
```

or

```
string="ipsum"

elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//p[contains(., '{string}')]").text
```

or

```
string="ipsum"

elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//p[contains(., '{}')]".format(string)).text
```

Comment: Hey, thanks:) While it works, I'm sorry as I didn't ask properly, so if you could assist me a bit further, please; how about only a part of my string matches the part of the text (ex: string = "Lorem ipsum et dolor", and text: <p>Lorem ipsum Foo</p> ), how to find a match of partial string in text?

Comment: In this case you can't , The string variable `string = "Lorem ipsum et dolor"` is different value and text `<p>Lorem ipsum Foo</p>` is different value. you have to change the  string variable to  this `string = "Lorem ipsum"` then only it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Given the sample HTML

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
<p>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
<p>Ut enim ad minim veniam</p>
<p>quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</p>
<p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur</p>
<p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident</p>
<p>sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
```

You could use the code

```
search_string = "Lorem sint"
for s in search_string.split(" "):
    print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//p[contains(text(), '{s}')]").text)
```

and it prints

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident
```

It just takes the search string, splits it by a space, and then searches for each word individually. You'll have to decide if this works for you or you can adapt it to better suit what you are looking for.